# OData don't connect with SAP Web IDE (local installation)

Tags: odata, sapui5

I used automatical OData connection with SAP Web IDE. Unfortunately, Data don't connect and Layout Editor says that Data Set "not defined". I have tried to connect by coding, for example `<Table items={/Stats}>`, but it doesn't work either. When I use project template (Master-Detail or Worklist), there are no problems with connection and Data is automatically connecting, but when I want to make my project and make a connection, there are always some problems.

Component.js

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
"sap/ui/Device",
"Statusverwaltung/model/models"
], function(UIComponent, Device, models) {
"use strict";

return UIComponent.extend("Statusverwaltung.Component", {

    metadata: {
        manifest: "json"
    },
    config : {
        "resourceBundle" : "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "titleResource" : "SHELL_TITLE",

        "serviceConfig" : {
            name: "UI5STAT1_SRV",
            serviceUrl: "/sap/opu/odata/kernc/UI5STAT1_SRV/"
        }
    },


    /**
     * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
     * @public
     * @override
     */
    init: function() {
        // call the base component's init function
        UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

        // set the device model
        this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
    }
});

});
```

Manifest.json

```
{
"_version": "1.1.0",
"sap.app": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "id": "Statusverwaltung",
    "type": "application",
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
    "applicationVersion": {
        "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "sourceTemplate": {
        "id": "servicecatalog.connectivityComponent",
        "version": "0.0.0"
    },
    "dataSources": {
        "UI5STAT1_SRV": {
            "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/kernc/UI5STAT1_SRV/",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0",
                "localUri": "webapp/localService/UI5STAT1_SRV/metadata.xml"
            }
        }
    }
},
"sap.ui": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "technology": "UI5",
    "icons": {
        "icon": "",
        "favIcon": "",
        "phone": "",
        "phone@2": "",
        "tablet": "",
        "tablet@2": ""
    },
    "deviceTypes": {
        "desktop": true,
        "tablet": true,
        "phone": true
    },
    "supportedThemes": ["sap_hcb", "sap_bluecrystal"]
},
"sap.ui5": {
    "_version": "1.1.0",
    "rootView": {
        "viewName": "Statusverwaltung.view.View",
        "type": "XML"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "minUI5Version": "1.30.0",
        "libs": {
            "sap.ui.core": {},
            "sap.m": {},
            "sap.ui.layout": {}
        }
    },
    "contentDensities": {
        "compact": true,
        "cozy": true
    },
    "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "Statusverwaltung.i18n.i18n"
            }
        }
    },
    "resources": {
        "css": [{
            "uri": "css/style.css"
        }]
    },
    "routing": {
        "targets": {
            "View": {
                "viewType": "XML",
                "transition": "slide",
                "clearAggregation": true,
                "viewName": "View",
                "viewId": "View"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

neo-app.json

```
     {


    "welcomeFile": "/webapp/index.html",
  "routes": [
    {
      "path": "/resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/test-resources",
      "target": {
        "type": "service",
        "name": "sapui5",
        "entryPath": "/test-resources"
      },
      "description": "SAPUI5 Test Resources"
    },
    {
      "path": "/sap/opu/odata",
      "target": {
        "type": "destination",
        "name": "v01",
        "entryPath": "/sap/opu/odata"
      },
      "description": "V01 description"
    }
  ],
  "sendWelcomeFileRedirect": true
}
```

.project.json

```
    {
  "projectType": [
    "sap.watt.uitools.ide.fiori",
    "sap.watt.uitools.ide.web",
    "sap.watt.saptoolsets.fiori.project.ui5template.smartProject",
    "sap.watt.saptoolsets.fiori.project.uiadaptation"
  ],
  "build": {
    "targetFolder": "dist",
    "sourceFolder": "webapp"
  },
  "generation": [
    {
      "templateId": "ui5template.basicSAPUI5ApplicationProject",
      "templateVersion": "1.32.0",
      "dateTimeStamp": "Mon, 17 Oct 2016 08:28:52 GMT"
    },
    {
      "templateId": "servicecatalog.connectivityComponent",
      "templateVersion": "0.0.0",
      "dateTimeStamp": "Mon, 17 Oct 2016 10:10:52 GMT"
    },
    {
      "templateId": "uiadaptation.changespreviewjs",
      "templateVersion": "0.0.0",
      "dateTimeStamp": "Tue, 18 Oct 2016 08:08:06 GMT"
    }
  ],
  "translation": {
    "translationDomain": "",
    "supportedLanguages": "en,fr,de",
    "defaultLanguage": "en",
    "defaultI18NPropertyFile": "i18n.properties",
    "resourceModelName": "i18n"
  },
  "basevalidator": {
    "services": {
      "xml": "fioriXmlAnalysis",
      "js": "fioriJsValidator"
    }
  },
  "codeCheckingTriggers": {
    "notifyBeforePush": true,
    "notifyBeforePushLevel": "Error",
    "blockPush": false,
    "blockPushLevel": "Error"
  },
  "mockpreview": {
    "mockUri": "/sap/opu/odata/kernc/UI5STAT1_SRV/",
    "metadataFilePath": "webapp/localService/UI5STAT1_SRV/metadata.xml",
    "loadJSONFiles": false,
    "loadCustomRequests": false,
    "mockRequestsFilePath": ""
  }
}
```

Comment: what problems are you referring to when you say: "There are always some problems"

Comment: I wanted to say that when I want to make a connection with my project, simple SAP UI5 Application, I cannot connect with SAP backend. But when I use template, I don't have problems and I get my data. And I have tried to compare code und find a difference...

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are never instantiating a model.
You can do that in the manifest.json

```json
   "models": {
        "i18n": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
            "settings": {
                "bundleName": "Statusverwaltung.i18n.i18n"
            }
        },
        "": {
            "dataSource":"UI5STAT1_SRV"
        }
    },
```

`""` defines the default model so you can use Bindingpaths like `{/Stats}`.